# Windows (7): virtual folders with newest files

Tags: windows-7

Is there a functionality in Windows (or a third party app) to have a virtual folder containing links to files from a physical directory (and it's sub directories) which are not older than, say, 7 days? Kind of like an SQL query in a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a build in tool for this - Windows Search / indexing.

Here is the configuration guide : http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/129437-windows-search-configure-use.html

From what i've seen in there you can build a query and specify the date to which you want to search.

I'm pretty sure windows does not provide a virtual folder with all files younger than 7 days. Would you really want to see in there all temporary data created by the browser while roaming the internet? thats a potentially large number of file tbh.

Comment: nice, as you can save the search this is exactly what I meant.